# Squid Cache Forwarding Loops

Tags: caching

I am running squid 3.1 on CentOS 6.6. Sometimes when a machine enters into the network it starts causing forwarding loops in squid and as a result it slows down the internet. Something like this keeps filling cache.log

```
2015/07/20 10:58:44| WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for:  
GET / HTTP/1.1  
Host: 10.0.5.50:3128  
Via: 1.0 squid.mydominname.com (squid/3.1.10), 1.1 squid.mydominname.com (squid/3.1.10)
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.5.143, 10.0.5.50  
Cache-Control: max-age=259200  
Connection: keep-alive
```

After sometime I also get file descriptor error like so;

> client_side.cc(2994) okToAccept: WARNING! Your cache is running out of
>   filedescriptors

X-Forwarded-For identifies the vulnerable machine. It happened in past that vulnerable machine contains suspicious software that caused this problem.

This doesn't happen all time but only when any bad machine enters into the network. Is there any squid configuration to prevent the network from that kind of forwarding loops?